# Export a thing to anything other than a single mesh?

Tags: saving

Anyway i try my thing becomes a single mesh when i export.

This is not useful for anything really and i am sure i have missed a basic klick somewhere.

How do i save it so the different parts are individually selectable and movable in another app?

Thanks!

Here are some more words.. not related to my question though, they are only here to please the system. I don't know why it's so picky.. makes me wonder, what questions do we never see because they are blocked by this system?

Comment: For questions about the use of this site use https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ and please be specific. What questions are blocked?

Comment: And please [edit] your questions and specify what format you are using to export and the specific steps you are following to do that.